# What is the Mac OSX Expose algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am looking for an algorithm to organise squares in space in a similar fashion the OSX expose feature does.

Thanks
- rS

Comment: Doesn't it just...line them up across in rows, and then down columns? I honestly don't remember it being anything special. Can you include an illustration or something that shows exactly what you want to implement?

Comment: It just arranges them into a grid...

Comment: The 10.5 version of Exposé has a different layout method, more like a 'optimal packing' approach. 10.6 is just boxes in a grid.

Answer (score 3):

It's more involved than just filling a grid if you actively try to minimize unused space, as windows can have different aspect ratios. See [this example](http://thinkmoult.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/2008-12-11-185721_1280x800_scrot.png). You can find code that does this in [KDE's kwin implementation of the Present Windows effect](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/KDE/kdebase/workspace/kwin/effects/presentwindows/).